# replace innerhtml from get().innerHTML with html()

Tags: html, jquery, innerhtml

I want to remove all instances of innerHTML from my code, but I'm unable to do so on this line:

```
$('div[id^="helpTextDiv"]').get(0).innerHTML=LoadStructure();
```

I know I can't use html with get:

```
$('div[id^="helpTextDiv"]').get(0).html();
```

Please suggest how to get rid of innerhtml from this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

[`.get(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the DOM element, you want [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('div[id^="helpTextDiv"]').eq(0).html("foo");
```

or at the selector level

```
$('div[id^="helpTextDiv"]:eq(0)').html("foo");
```